Is there a way to generate a random unitary, but with specified elements in the diagonal?
I'm trying to generate a random Unitary Operator for a classifier task in a Open Quantum System. In this problem, this operator must contain the classifying vector (let's call it $X$) elements in its diagonal.
$U$ acts on a composed Hilbert Space, i.e., it acts on $\mathcal{H_{\text{system}}} \otimes \mathcal{H_{\text{environment}}}$, in which the dimensions of Hilbert Spaces are $2-D$ and $S-D$, respectively. Thus, the dimension of $U$ is equal to double the dimension of $X$.
I'm using the code below to build the Unitary:
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.stats import unitary_group

N_features=2
N_qubits=math.ceil(np.log2(N_features)+1)
X=np.random.rand(N_features)
X_new=np.append(X,X)
U = np.matrix(unitary_group.rvs(2**N_qubits))
np.fill_diagonal(U,X_new)


How can I build this random operator, but with determined elements, and be assured that $U$ still is unitary? The diagonal must not be necessarily the elements of $X$, but it must contains $X$ elements.

Crossposted from Physics.SE

Please mark crossposts as such.

Can you give a small numerical example of what you wish to do? I'm not sure to understand what $X$ is here

@tristannemoz X is a features vector of a dataset. For example, X = [0.97992262, 0.19937816]
